# Swift: how to always get different value from shuffled array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, shuffle

I created an array of words basically inside of a button, and each time I press my button I get a random item from the array. Now sometimes I get identical items. What if I don't want my items to repeat themselves and I always want to get new items? (Obviously I even want them to repeat their cycle after they all have ben showed once).

```
@IBOutlet weak var shoppingLabel : UILabel!
@IBAction func shoppingListButton(_ sender: Any) {
         var shoppingList = ["Oranges","Apples","Broccoli"].shuffled()
        print(shoppingList)
        resultLabel.text = shoppingList.first ?? ""
    }
```

this is not a duplicate as the similar question has an array outside of the button and is a var array, mine is a let. With my array I'm unable to remove items from it because it can't be changed, and no, I can't make it a var array...

Answer (score 1):

To cycle through a random array:

1. Create the array
2. Shuffle it once
3. Pick values by cycling through the array from the beginning to the end

To achieve 1) and 2) simply define the array as a constant and shuffle it outside the method in which you want to use it.

To achieve 3) create an additional variable to keep track of which index of the array you are currently at, and increment it after picking a value.

To make sure you don't go beyond the bounds of the array and to achieve the "cycling" through of the array, reset the index to 0 when the index becomes greater than the last index of the array. A simple way to do this, is to use the remainder operator % in Swift.

E.g.

```
let shoppingList = ["Oranges", "Apples", "Broccoli"].shuffled()
var currentIndex = 0

@IBAction func shoppingListButton(_ sender: Any) {

    // pick an item
    let nextItem = shoppingList[currentIndex]

    // update the label
    resultLabel.text = nextItem

    // increment the index to cycle through items
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % shoppingList.count
}
```

---

To pick random non-repeating values from an array:

1. Create the array
2. Pick a random value from the array
3. If the picked value equals the last value, pick a new one

To achieve 2) use the randomElement() function to pick a random element. This is less computationally expensive than shuffling the entire array and picking the first element each time.

To achieve 3) use a while loop or similar to keep picking random elements until a new one is generated.

E.g.

```
let shoppingList = ["Oranges", "Apples", "Broccoli"]

@IBAction func shoppingListButton(_ sender: Any) {

    // pick a random element that is not equal to the last one
    var nextItem: String?
    repeat {
        nextItem = shoppingList.randomElement()
    } while nextItem == resultLabel.text

    // update the label
    resultLabel.text = nextItem
}
```

Comment: You may want to comment on the use of the modulo. I understand it, but the OP/future readers may not.

Comment: I still get repeated values, how do you update the label?

Comment: This approach should not yield repeated values, only the cycle will repeat. Do you also want to randomness between cycles?

Comment: yes thanks!  but i also have a problem with the label: what command should I give it i order for it to display the always different words?    resultLabel.text = shoppingList.first ?? "" right now it's like this but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Alright check the second example of my updated answer, it should do what I understand you need.

Comment: I am sorry, I'm still unable to make it work :(